# Is it possible to change the star size on Telerik RadRating for UWP?

Tags: c#, telerik, visual-studio-2017, windows-10-universal

I found a thread, and codes are there, but it doesn't work

https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-change-the-size-of-the-rating-item-star

link wrote, I could use

```
<telerikInput.RadRating>
    <telerikInput.RadRatingItem ShapeWidth="50" />
</telerikInput.RadRating>
```

but there's no ShapeWidth in RadRatingItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document you linked is for Windows phone. For UWP please reference the [newest official document](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/universal-windows-platform/controls/radrating/features/rating-properties). So that there is no property named `ShapeWidth` from the properties page. For changing the star size you could just update the default style of `RadRating`. The size of the `SymbolIcon` is just defined by the `FontSize` property of `RadRating`. For example:

```
<telerikInput:RadRating FontSize="500" >
   <!--<telerikInput:RadRating.Style>
       <Style TargetType="telerikInput:RadRating"> 
           <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="500" />  
       </Style> 
   </telerikInput:RadRating.Style>-->
   <telerikInput:RadRatingItem /> 
</telerikInput:RadRating>
```

Even if you want to change the deep style that cannot be changed by properties you could update the default style like I showed above. For the default style please reference [`Generic.xaml`](https://github.com/telerik/UI-For-UWP/blob/master/Controls/Input/Input.UWP/Themes/Generic.xaml).

Comment: I'm too late, anyway, Thanks alot!